# "La Vie En Rose" - Man to woman instead of woman to man

Tags: traduction, pronoms, genre

I really love the song "La Vie En Rose" by Edith Piaf, but there's something that bothers me whenever I sing the song. The song's voice is a woman talking concerning and man.

Being a man, I don't want to be singing a song with lyrics meaning "when he takes me in his arms" (Quand il me prend dans ses bras).

Can anyone take a look at the lyrics I've given below and change them to where it's a man talking about a woman?

Additionally, perhaps a version were the language is gender neutral? (Using "you" and "your"
 etc. instead of "he" and "him". )

Kind of a strange request I know.

> Quand il me prend dans ses bras
>   Il me parle tout bas,
>   Je vois la vie en rose.
>
> Il me dit des mots d'amour,
>    Des mots de tous les jours,
>    Et ça me fait quelque chose.
>
> Il est entré dans mon cœur
>    Une part de bonheur
>    Dont je connais la cause.
>
> C'est lui pour moi. Moi pour lui.
>    Dans la vie,
>    Il me l'a dit, l'a juré pour la vie.
>
> Et dès que je l’aperçois
>   Alors je sens en moi
>   Mon cœur qui bat.

(Also, could someone help out with the tags? I'm new to both the French Language and this Stack Exchange and don't know very much. I've currently marked it "pronoms". :) )

Comment: That can be debated according to your preferences, but "Quand il me prend dans ses bras" could still be the man that take the girl in his arms, so you may want to use: "Quand je la prends dans mes bras/Quand je te prends dans mes bras", in other words, how do you "imagine/see it": You enlace the other, or the other enlaces you? Who starts the action?

Comment: Are the rights to La Vie en Rose extinct? If they are not, you are asking people to commit an infraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is to use the second person (ie. tu)

> Quand **tu** me prends dans **tes** bras
>    **Tu** me parles tout bas
>    je vois la vie en rose
>
> **Tu** me dis des mots d'amour
>    Des mots de tous les jours
>    Et ça me fait quelque chose
>
> Il est entré dans mon cœur
>   Une part de bonheur
>   Dont je connais la cause
>
> C'est **toi** pour **moi**
>   **Moi** pour **toi**
>   Dans la vie
>   **Tu** me l'as dit, l'a juré pour la vie
>
> Et dès que je **t**'aperçois
>   Alors je sens en moi,
>   Mon cœur qui bat...

It could be used for a man or a woman without changing anything.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted. I think I mentioned the possibility of using "you" in my OP, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Bonsoir,

Voici les paroles modifiées :

> Quand **elle** me prend dans ses bras
> Qu'**elle** me parle tout bas
> Je vois la vie en rose
>
> **Elle** me dit des mots d'amour
> Des mots de tous les jours
> Et ça me fait quelque chose
>
> Il est entré dans mon cœur
> Une part de bonheur
> Dont je connais la cause
>
> C'est **elle** pour moi
> Moi pour **elle**
> Dans la vie
> **Elle** me l'a dit
> L'a juré, pour la vie
>
> Et dès que je l’aperçois
> Alors je sens en moi
> Mon cœur qui bat.

Je ne connais pas de version 'neutre' de cette chanson.

Comment: Il faut conserver « **Il** est entré dans mon cœur »

Comment: @Toto Why do you want to keep the _"Il"_ ?

Comment: @Nathan: C'est « Une part de bonheur » qui « est entré dans mon cœur » et non pas la personne dont on parle.

Comment: And moreover the *il* in that sentence is not a pronoun even for *une part* but the impersonal *il*

Comment: @Toto,Nathan,Luke: Well, to agree (or disagree) with everyone, my take is that it's up to interpretation. It could be either an impersonal pronoun or a personal pronoun if the following is meant as a nominal sentence.

Comment: @Toto Actually, it doesn't matter, as _"une part de bonheur"_ is feminine too. But as Stéphane said, if it's meant as "Il se fait qu'est entré dans mon coeur une part de bonheur", then "il" is impersonal. I believe this is the correct interpretation too.